# Resetting selectInput to NULL in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I need to be able to reset several selectInput widgets in R Shiny back to their original value of NULL (with a blank text region in the widget).  So far, I'm getting the user input (which variable to use as the x axis) like this:

```
  output$descrxaxis_Variable <- renderUI({
  selectInput(inputId = "descrxaxis", label = "Choose x axis variable", choices = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars$df), multiple = TRUE)})
```

I'm getting the column index of that variable using this:

```
 x_ind <- reactiveValues(val = NULL)
observeEvent(input$descrxaxis, {
  x_ind$val <- which(colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars$df) == input$descrxaxis)})
```

What I need to be able to do is reset x_ind to NULL, so that when the user clicks a "Reset X axis" button, the column they previously chose is gone.  Here is my current code for doing this:

```
    observeEvent(input$descrXaxisResetBtn, {
    updateSelectInput("descrxaxis", label = "Choose x axis variable", choices = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars$df), multiple = TRUE, selected = NULL)})
```

But, I've also tried:

```
  observeEvent(input$descrXaxisResetBtn, {
    shinyjs::useShinyjs()
    shinyjs::reset("descrxaxis")})
```

Neither of these have worked, and the previous variable they chose remains in the widget text box.  How do I get this to work?  Thank you.

EDIT: Here is the code that works (with the help of those who answered my question).

```
ui <- navbarPage(title = "SD Mesonet Quality Control", id = "navbarPage",
                     tabPanel(title = 'Metadata',
                              sidebarLayout(
                                sidebarPanel(width = 2,
                                             h4("Select Summary Variables to Plot"),
                                             div(style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:bottom; position:relative",
                                                 fluidRow(
                                                   column(10,
                                                          uiOutput("descrxaxis_Variable")),
                                                   column(2,
                                                          actionButton(inputId = "descrXaxisResetBtn", label = "Reset X", style = "padding:17px; color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"))
                                                 )
                                             ),        
                                             div(style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:bottom; position:relative",
                                                 fluidRow(
                                                   column(10,
                                                          uiOutput("descryaxis_Variable")),
                                                   column(2,
                                                          actionButton(inputId = "descrYaxisResetBtn", label = "Reset Y", style = "padding:17px; color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"))
                                                 )
                                             ),           
                                             div(style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:bottom; position:relative",
                                                 fluidRow(
                                                   column(10,
                                                          uiOutput("descrfacet_Variable")),
                                                   column(2,
                                                          actionButton(inputId = "descrFacetResetBtn", label = "Reset Facet", style = "padding:17px; color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"))
                                                 )
                                             ),        
                                             div(style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:bottom; position:relative",
                                                 fluidRow(
                                                   column(10,
                                                          uiOutput("descrcolor_Variable")),
                                                   column(2,
                                                          actionButton(inputId = "descrColorResetBtn", label = "Reset Color", style = "padding:17px; color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"))
                                                 )
                                             ),
                                             br(),
                                             actionButton("descrBtnPlot","Plot", style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4")
                                             
                                ),
                                mainPanel(width = 10,
                                          plotlyOutput("descrSummaryStatsPlot")
                                )
                              )
                     )
    )
    
    server <- function(input,output,session){
      output$descrxaxis_Variable <- renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId = "descrxaxis", label = "Choose x axis variable", choices = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars), multiple = TRUE, selected = character(0))})
      
      output$descryaxis_Variable <- renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId = "descryaxis", label = "Choose y axis variable", choices = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars), multiple = TRUE)})
      
      output$descrfacet_Variable <- renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId = "descrfacet", label = "Choose facet variable", choices = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars), multiple = TRUE)})
      
      output$descrcolor_Variable <- renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId = "descrcolor", label = "Choose color variable", choices = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars), multiple = TRUE)})
      
      x_ind <- reactiveValues(val = NULL)
      observeEvent(input$descrxaxis, {
        x_ind$val <- which(colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars) == input$descrxaxis)})
      
      y_ind <- reactiveValues(val = NULL)
      observeEvent(input$descryaxis, {
        y_ind$val <- which(colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars) == input$descryaxis)})
      
      facet_ind <- reactiveValues(val = NULL)
      observeEvent(input$descrfacet, {
        facet_ind$val <- which(colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars) == input$descrfacet)})
      
      color_ind <- reactiveValues(val = NULL)
      observeEvent(input$descrcolor, {
        color_ind$val <- which(colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars) == input$descrcolor)})
      
      observeEvent(input$descrBtnPlot,{
        if (!is.null(x_ind$val) & !is.null(y_ind$val) & is.null(facet_ind$val) & is.null(color_ind$val)){
          p <- ggplot(descrDataMelted_selVars, aes_string(x = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars)[x_ind$val], y = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars)[y_ind$val])) + geom_point()}
        
        if (!is.null(x_ind$val) & !is.null(y_ind$val) & is.null(facet_ind$val) & !is.null(color_ind$val)){
          p <- ggplot(descrDataMelted_selVars, aes_string(x = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars)[x_ind$val], y = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars)[y_ind$val],
                                                          color = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars)[color_ind$val])) + geom_point()}
        
        if (!is.null(x_ind$val) & !is.null(y_ind$val) & !is.null(facet_ind$val) & is.null(color_ind$val)){
          p <- ggplot(descrDataMelted_selVars, aes_string(x = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars)[x_ind$val], y = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars)[y_ind$val])) + geom_point() +
            facet_wrap(as.formula(paste("~",colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars)[facet_ind$val])))}
        
        if (!is.null(x_ind$val) & !is.null(y_ind$val) & !is.null(facet_ind$val) & !is.null(color_ind$val)){
          p <- ggplot(descrDataMelted_selVars, aes_string(x = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars)[x_ind$val], y = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars)[y_ind$val],
                                                          color = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars)[color_ind$val])) + geom_point() +
            facet_wrap(as.formula(paste("~",colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars)[facet_ind$val])))}
        
        output$descrSummaryStatsPlot <- renderPlotly(p)
      })
      
      observeEvent(input$descrXaxisResetBtn, {
        updateSelectInput(session,"descrxaxis", selected = character(0))
      })
      
    }
    shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, i.e. a complete (short) running shiny app. Besides trying to set `input$descraxis` to `NULL`, you could set `input$descraxis` to `""` and `x_ind$val <- NULL`

Comment: I will create an example and edit this post.  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I posted a reproducible example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64298168/how-to-reset-selectinput-choices-in-r-shiny.  It has code to make it run, with example data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up front, use `selected=character(0)` (or `selected=""`, as @starja commented):

```r
    updateSelectInput("descrxaxis", label = "Choose x axis variable",
                      choices = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars$df), multiple = TRUE, 
                      selected = character(0))
```

Some key components from your [other (duplicate) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64298168/how-to-reset-selectinput-choices-in-r-shiny) that need to be fixed, and are relevant to the concept of updating inputs (but not obvious based on the current state of *this* question):

- First, do not nest `observe` or `observeEvent` within another one. This might be a typo in your code there, but make sure that all `observe*` (and any reactive function, for that matter) functions are effectively on the "top-level" of the `server` function.

  Change from

  ```r
        observeEvent(input$descrBtnPlot,{
          ...
          output$descrSummaryStatsPlot <- renderPlotly(p)


          observeEvent(input$descrXaxisResetBtn, {
            updateSelectInput("descrxaxis", selected = character(0))
          })
        })
  ```

  to

  ```r
        observeEvent(input$descrBtnPlot,{
          ...
          output$descrSummaryStatsPlot <- renderPlotly(p)
        })
        observeEvent(input$descrXaxisResetBtn, {
          updateSelectInput("descrxaxis", selected = character(0))
        })
  ```

  (though this is incomplete, see the next point).
- Second, the first argument of any `update*` function is the `session`. This is not optional. The code in bullet 1 above should really be

  ```r
        observeEvent(input$descrBtnPlot,{
          ...
          output$descrSummaryStatsPlot <- renderPlotly(p)
        })
        observeEvent(input$descrXaxisResetBtn, {
          updateSelectInput(session, "descrxaxis", selected = character(0))
          #                 ^^^^^^^^ the only difference
        })
  ```

  This leads me to the last bullet:
- Third, your `server <- function(input, output)` is fine when you don't use any `update*` functions, but in line with the second point above, you must have `session`, which means you need to change your server definition to

  ```r
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    ...
  }
  ```

---

I'll use the example from `?updateSelectInput` to demonstrate how to find the right answer, but injecting a single `browser()` before the actual call.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  p("The checkbox group controls the select input"),
  checkboxGroupInput("inCheckboxGroup", "Input checkbox",
    c("Item A", "Item B", "Item C")),
  selectInput("inSelect", "Select input",
    c("Item A", "Item B", "Item C"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    x <- input$inCheckboxGroup

    # Can use character(0) to remove all choices
    if (is.null(x))
      x <- character(0)

    browser()

    # Can also set the label and select items
    updateSelectInput(session, "inSelect",
      label = paste("Select input label", length(x)),
      choices = x,
      selected = tail(x, 1)
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

1. When you run this the first time, it'll start with an empty selector, so we can just `c`ontinue out of that debugger.
2. Select an item. The call to `updateSelectInput` sets `selected = tail(x, 1)`, so if we run that on the console, we'll see

   ```r
   Browse[2]> tail(x, 1)
   [1] "Item A"
   ```

   `c`ontinue out of this debugger, notice the selector now says `Item A`.
3. Deselect the "A" checkbox, and you'll be in the debugger again.

   ```r
   Browse[4]> tail(x, 1)
   character(0)
   ```

   `c`ontinue out of this debugger, and you'll see the selector is now empty (deselected).

Why? Internally, looking at the source for `updateSelectInput` (as of 1.4.0.2),

```r
updateSelectInput
# function (session, inputId, label = NULL, choices = NULL, selected = NULL) 
# {
#     choices <- if (!is.null(choices)) 
#         choicesWithNames(choices)
#     if (!is.null(selected)) 
#         selected <- as.character(selected)
#     options <- if (!is.null(choices)) 
#         selectOptions(choices, selected)
#     message <- dropNulls(list(label = label, options = options, 
#         value = selected))
#     session$sendInputMessage(inputId, message)
# }
# <bytecode: 0x00000000b8f06030>
# <environment: namespace:shiny>
```

see that all it checks is `!is.null(selected)`, so your thought to use `selected=NULL` is both its default value and it is used as the choice to "do not change the selected value".

---

As a more specific example, I'll start with the (non-debugged) version of that app, and add a single "Reset!" button that will clear the selection in the `selectInput`:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  p("The checkbox group controls the select input"),
  checkboxGroupInput("inCheckboxGroup", "Input checkbox",
    c("Item A", "Item B", "Item C")),
  selectInput("inSelect", "Select input",
    c("Item A", "Item B", "Item C")),
  actionButton("resetsel", "Reset!")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    x <- input$inCheckboxGroup

    # Can use character(0) to remove all choices
    if (is.null(x))
      x <- character(0)

    # Can also set the label and select items
    updateSelectInput(session, "inSelect",
      label = paste("Select input label", length(x)),
      choices = x,
      selected = tail(x, 1)
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$resetsel, {
    ### either
    updateSelectInput(session, "inSelect", selected = character(0))
    ### or
    # updateSelectInput(session, "inSelect", selected = "")
    ### both do the same thing here
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now, the basic operation of the shiny demo works, but when you click on the reset button, the selection is cleared. FYI, if you don't have changes for `choices=`, you don't need to include that in your call to `updateSelectInput`. It doesn't hurt, but it is only necessary if you believe the list of choices may need to be updated/changed otherwise.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  Unfortunately, I honestly don't quite follow what you're doing here.  I posted a new question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64298168/how-to-reset-selectinput-choices-in-r-shiny, with some data and the code to make an example run.

Comment: (1) It is discouraged to ask the same question twice. Delete that question, [edit] this question, and add the relevant information there. (2) My first paragraph literally says what to do: use `selected=""` or `selected=character(0)`. Using either of those, you are clearing the selection in the `selectInput` selector. The rest of the question was just tracing *how* to see what is happening in the canonical example that successfully clears the select input.

Comment: You have several mistakes in that question's code. (1) `server <- function(input, output, session) ...`, you forgot session, needed to update any input elements. (2) You nested one `observeEvent` within the other. (3) You missed `session` again, required first parameter of `updateSelectInput`. When you fix all three of those, your app works (though the current layout of the buttons is not ideal).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your patience.