# updateSelectInput fails to clear input object

Tags: r, shiny

In an R Shiny app, when trying to blank-out the choices and selection of a select object using the `updateSelectInput()` function, the `input` object does not reset. The `input` object retains the last choice selected.

The choice and selection are indeed removed from the select dropdown as I set them to `character(0)` ([per references](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.7.0/updateSelectInput.html)), but the `input` object resists reseting. Here is a very [hackish solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69078326/updateselectinput-does-not-update-the-inputid-value-of-selectinput) I'm trying to avoid.

Is there a way to reset an `input` object to `NULL`, or `character(0)`? I know `input` is read only, but I'm wondering if I can reset it when the selectInput has been reset.

```
library(shiny)

cs <- c("A","B")

ui <- basicPage(
  selectInput("options","Select", choices=NULL, selected = NULL),
  actionButton("add","Add options"),
  actionButton("clear","Clear options"),
  verbatimTextOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$clear, {
    updateSelectInput(session,"options",
                      choices = character(0), 
                      selected = character(0))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    updateSelectInput(session,"options",
                      choices = c("A","B"), 
                      selected = NULL)
  })
  
  output$text <- renderPrint({
    str(input$options)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `selectInput` never produces a `NULL`, at best it only yields an empty string `""` when first rendered.

Comment: Except when `multiple = T`, then when nothing is selected the input is `NULL`. I tried reseting it to `""` and it doesn't take.

Comment: Is using as choices argument a string saying `"NULL"` and then use it to create an if else inside a `reactive`  an option?

Comment: That's an interesting idea, may try it. Thanks you! Seems like a long roundabout though.  I'm also trying to solve the problem by checking if the input value exists in the new conditions, if it does it means it's newly set, if it doesn't, it means it's the old value that didn't get reset.

Comment: Why do you need a NULL per se? If you need it downstream somewhere, you might make a reactive along the lines of `reactive(if(input$mysel == "",NULL,input$mysel))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the argument selectize to FALSE can produce a NULL.

```
ui <- basicPage(
  selectInput("options",
   "Select",
   choices = NULL,
   selected = NULL,
   selectize = FALSE
  ),
  actionButton("add","Add options"),
  actionButton("clear","Clear options"),
  verbatimTextOutput("text")
)
```

Comment: Ha! Great! Why didn't I try that?!! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Its to do with internal implementation of the `updateSelectInput` as per [Resetting selectInput to NULL in R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64296326/resetting-selectinput-to-null-in-r-shiny), not ideal but try adding an extra space to `"clear it"`

```
  observeEvent(input$clear, {
    updateSelectInput(session,"options",choices = " ", selected = " ")
  })
```

Comment: Thanks! I did tried that. It looks weird, the select dropdown has like a bottom extra spacing or something. Plus, I would have to add a check to exclude those values at the time of using the input value. Good idea, but too hackish.